# append xpath to element

Tags: javascript, xpath, nightwatch.js

I use a page object with an element like

```
myButton: {
    selector: '//button[@ng-click="$clientCtrl.add()"]',
    locateStrategy: 'xpath'
}
```

While my test is running, I expect my button to be disabled.
I **could** add a new element like this:

```
myButtonDisabled: {
    selector: '//button[@ng-click="$clientCtrl.add()"][@disabled="disabled"]',
    locateStrategy: 'xpath'
}
```

But I have many buttons, so I would get a huge list of enabled and disabled buttons.
So instead I'd like to write a command inside my page object like this:

```
var myCommands = {
    assertButtonDisabled: function(mybutton) {
        this.api
            .pause(500)
            .useXpath()
            .expect.element(mybutton + '[@disabled="disabled"]', 5000).to.be.present;
        return this;
    }
};
```

which I call inside my test via

```
myPageObject.assertButtonDisabled('@myButton');
```

Well, this fails because I cannot concatenate an element like `@myButton` with an additional xpath (`[@disabled="disabled"]`).

So what can I do instead of adding multiple new elements?

Answer (score 0):

From maintainability perspective it would be much easier to maintain things this way:

```
myButton: {
selector: '//button[@ng-click="$clientCtrl.add()"]',
locateStrategy: 'xpath'
}

myButtonDisabled: {
selector: '//button[@ng-click="$clientCtrl.add()"][@disabled="disabled"]',
locateStrategy: 'xpath'
}
```

Just use proper naming for those elements.